# Using Google.Cloud.Storage with user authentication

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am writing an application in C# which would run on a PC and allow a user to login to GCP and manage files there.

I looked at the sample codes on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

The documents show how to use a service account for authentication, but I want to use user authentication.

In this way, if the user do not have permission to say delete data, the application can not do it. If I use a service account, which I don't want.

Is there any way that I use user authentication to log in to cloud storage services?

Is there any sample that I can use for this purpose?

## Update 1

My main aim is to develop an application similar to gsutil but in C# and it should authenticate users similar to gsutils.

The same as gsutil, it would be used only by cloud admins who already have access to buckets via gsutils or cloud.google.com

Is the source code for gsutils published? How does it authenticate users?

Comment: Yes, you can using Google OAuth. However, Google is restricting the creation of clients that can access Google Cloud directly. A better choice is to manage authorization directly in your web server and pass the user short lived tokens. The best choice is that your web app makes all requests for the user, but this means you will need to manage user authorization (you can still use Google OAuth for authentication and identity). Here is a link for Google OAuth: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: @JohnHanley The main problem is that there is no web server and nothing runs on the cloud for this part of the project. I am writing a small application that is a utility for cloud developers to manage data on the cloud.

Comment: That limits you to OAuth Implicit Grant which is not secure and the user can only grant access to their data and not to data you own/control. You will need to implement a service in the cloud or on a web server where you can implement OAuth on your own web server, Firebase, etc. Read this link on Implicit Grant: https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/

Answer (score 0):

What you might be wanted to use is this ["User account credentials"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#user_accounts). This at the ends guides you to [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/), which supports email and password authentication as well as federated sign in with identity providers such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, and GitHub.

You can sign in users to your Firebase app either by using FirebaseUI as a complete drop-in auth solution or by using the Firebase Authentication SDK to manually integrate one or several sign-in methods into your app. This will be up to your needs and how you want to build your app.

Comment: Please see my update which explains the type of application that I want to develop in C#

Comment: Given that, I think that just as mentioned in previous comments, you would need to create a cloud service in order to implement your solution the way you desire.